# Reference request for a result in additive combinatorics

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number and $[p-1]=\{1, 2, \ldots, p-1\}$.
The following proposition is proved: (but I cannot find out *where*)

> Proposition: The non-empty subset sums of $[p-1]$ are equally distributed
> $\pmod{p}$.

In other words, if $N(a)$ denotes the number of non-empty subset sums which are $\equiv a\pmod{p}$ then $N(a)=\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$, for every integer $0\le a\le p-1$.

I can prove it on my own in many ways, but I thought since this is already known, to put just a reference next to this result.

Can anybody give me some reference (paper or book) where I can find a proof of this proposition?

Comment: crossposted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4543208/87355

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, but before 16 days with no response. I hope this is ok.

Comment: it's OK, but best practice is to disclose the crossposting on both ends; just to avoid any duplication of efforts.

Comment: Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. If the elements of a subset $S$ add up to $a\ne0$, then the elements of $g^rS$ add up to $g^ra$. This runs through all the nonzero elements modulo $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I said I know how to prove it. I just asked for a reference. If there is any.

Comment: (a) you need $p$ to be odd.  (b) The claim is equivalent (by taking Fourier transforms) to $(-1)^{p-1} \Phi_p(-1)=1$ where $\Phi_p(t) = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (t - e^{2\pi ij/p})$ is the $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial, but this is immediate from the classical formula $\Phi_p(t) = 1 + t + \dots + t^{p-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you a reference for a proof, but I can't give you a reference for a proof of $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, either. Some things are so easy to prove that no one feels the need to publish a proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the proposition I mention is not so easy to prove. Anyway, I suppose that there is no reference at all.